# Using a list as a string of the name and the elements within the list

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, loops

Is there a way to make a list of lists and then loop through them.

Essentially I need to use the elements of multiple lists as a condition but also use the name of the as a string / column name.

I Know the example below can be done in a easier way, but I think it needs this approach as my task is a bit more complex than the below

```
 df=

    name
0   Alice
1   Fred
2   George

male=['fred','george']
female=['alice','emily']


alllists=[male, female]

for i in alllists:
    df[i]=0

    df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('|'.join(i),na=False),l]=1
```

Output df

```
    name    Male   Female  
0   Alice    0      1      
1   Fred    1       0      
2   George  1        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is a way, it's not recommended. Just use a dictionary:

```
d = {'male': ['fred', 'george'],
     'female': ['alice', 'emily']}

for k, v in d.items():
    mask = df['name'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(v), na=False)
    df[k.capitalize()] = mask.astype(int)
```

`mask.astype(int)` works because a Boolean array may be mapped directly to `1` / `0`, just as `bool` is a subclass of `int` in regular Python.

Result:

```
print(df)

     name  Male  Female
0   Alice     0       1
1    Fred     1       0
2  George     1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).

```
>>> males = {'fred', 'george'}
>>> fm = pd.get_dummies(['Male' if name.lower() in males else 'Female' for name in df['name']])
>>> result = pd.concat([df, fm], axis=1)
>>> 
>>> result
     name  Female  Male
0   Alice       1     0
1    Fred       0     1
2  George       0     1
```

This can be done much more elegantly by using a better data structure, like a `dict` to map names to sexes:

```
>>> sex = {'Fred': 'Male', 'George': 'Male', 'Alice': 'Female', 'Emily': 'Female'}
>>> result = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['name'].map(sex))], axis=1)
>>> result
     name  Female  Male
0   Alice       1     0
1    Fred       0     1
2  George       0     1
```

If we have to start from

```
male = ['fred','george']
female = ['alice','emily']
```

you can build `sex` like this:

```
>>> sex = {name.capitalize():s for names, s in [(male, 'Male'), (female, 'Female')]
...:                           for name in names}
...:                           
>>> sex
{'Alice': 'Female', 'Emily': 'Female', 'Fred': 'Male', 'George': 'Male'}
```

Finally, if the order of the columns is important, you can reindex the result.

```
>>> result = result.reindex(columns=['name', 'Male', 'Female'])
>>> result
     name  Male  Female
0   Alice     0       1
1    Fred     1       0
2  George     1       0
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this makes a lot of sense